# Rattle R not loading data

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset, pmml, rattle

I'm trying to load a library dataset into Rattle but I keep getting the following error:

> "Error in ifelse(pmmlCanExport(variables[i]), "", Rtxt(". No code export")) :
>         could not find function "pmmlCanExport"

Sometimes it doesn't throw the error but only the first column loads, not the whole data set.

I have the `pmml` package installed and loaded.

I've tried loading an **R** data frame and a CSV also, same problem...

Anyone encounter this?

Using Windows 7 Professional 64 bit, tried with **R** versions 3.01 and 3.02.  Same error.

Traceback shows:

```
> traceback()
9: ifelse(pmmlCanExport(variables[i]), "", Rtxt(". No code export"))
8: createVariablesModel(colnames(crs$dataset))
7: executeDataTab()
6: dispatchExecuteButton()
5: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
4: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
3: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
2: tryCatch(dispatchExecuteButton(), interrupt = function(m) setStatusBar(Rtxt("Processing interrupted by user.")), 
       finally = set.cursor())
1: (function (action, window) 
   {
       if (!is.null(crv$executing) && crv$executing) 
           return()
       crv$executing <- TRUE
       on.exit(crv$executing <- FALSE)
       setStatusBar()
       theWidget("rattle_window")$setFocus()
       set.cursor("watch")
       tryCatch(dispatchExecuteButton(), interrupt = function(m) setStatusBar(Rtxt("Processing interrupted by user.")), 
           finally = set.cursor())
       return()
   })(<pointer: 0x000000000fa38c80>)
```

Comment: Does `getAnywhere("pmmlCanExport")` find it?

Comment: I get "no object named ‘pmmlCanExport’ was found" same as Christian below...

Comment: What is the output from `treaceback()` after you get the error message?

Comment: edited with traceback () output...

Comment: OK, so where is `createVariablesModel`?  It's likely that `pmmlCanExport` is in the same package.  Try `getAnywhere("createVariablesModel")` or `find("createVariablesModel")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem.

Downloaded the old version of PMML:
http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/pmml/pmml_1.3.tar.gz

installed from source:
    R CMD INSTALL pmml_1.3.tar.gz

It appears to work for now. Not sure if the downgrade will affect something else.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem; `getAnywhere("pmmlCanExport")` returns `no object named ‘pmmlCanExport’ was found`. Tested on Win7 x64, R 3.0.2 & R 2.15.3.

Comment: Hi Christian. Welcome to SO.  Since this doesn't provide a solution, it should really be included as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Hi Richie, thank you for welcoming me. I tried to comment at first, but it seems that as a new user, I cannot comment on questions from others, only my own (i.e., I see a "comment" link beneath my message but not beneath Dirk Calloway's). If I am missing something, please give me a hint. [I tried to add the new information that it doesn't work on R 2.x either, but was unsure if I could just edit the original message, which I obviously can]

Comment: You need 50 reputation to be able to comment anywhere. (It's a spam prevention feature).